# Logging out of math.SE

Tags: support

I wanted to log out but I was given this message:

> Clicking Log Out will clear all local credentials in your browser, and log you out on all devices.

Does this mean my user will be cleared?

Answer (score 4):

No, when they say "credentials" they just mean the browser cookie - when you go to the site, it won't know to log you in. Your user account will be perfectly intact :)

Comment: **if** you have a registered user account. If you are unregistered....

Answer (score 3):

This message means that logging out in one place will log you out elsewhere.

If you log from home and from your phone, for example, logging out from your phone will cause your compurer to be logged out as well.